# how to add a Fragment in first position of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using the pagerIndicator i need to add a fragment at position 0

for example if i have Title1,Title2,Title3 and i want to add Title0 in position 0
so my ViewPager look like this Title0,Title1,Title2,Title3

i have tried something like this

```
mAdapter.setCONTACTS(New_Contacts); // String[] New_Contacts 
mAdapter.setCount(New_Contacts.length);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and my Adapter is :

```
public class My_FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    String[] CONTACTS_ID;



    public  String[] getCONTACTS() {
        return CONTACTS_ID;
    }

    public  void setCONTACTS(String[] cONTACTS) {
        CONTACTS_ID = cONTACTS;
    }

    private int mCount;

    public My_FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return My_Fragment.newInstance(CONTACTS[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

the Problem  is that the content inside Title0 become the Content of Title1 
and the content inside Title1 become the Content of Title2...

i don't know what's goin on !

Comment: We have no idea what setCONTACTS or setCount does.  All I can guess is you're using a TitlePageIndicator, you're adding a new fragment, and your not adding a new title.

Comment: yes i am using TitlePageIndicator ... i will edit my question